# Java media Streaming Humble-video

Tags: java, streaming

Пожалуйста помогите мне с Java Humble-Video. Я пробовал несколько раз, но проблему не решил. Мне нужно конвертировать видео файлы, например, из mp4 в flv формат.

Comment: вы знакомы с `IMediaReader` ?